# Switch if variable includes partial value, PHP

Tags: php

I have many "partial" words that may be input in the variable "$_source" - I have only listed 4 for brevity. Is there a CASE/Switch option that would perform better? and if so can you provide a small example using only two or three

```
if(strpos($_POST['$source'],'boy') !== false) {
    $gender = 'M';
}
if(strpos($_POST['$source'],'man') !== false) {
    $gender = 'M';
}
if(strpos($_POST['$source_url'],'gir') !== false) {
    $gender = 'F';
}
if(strpos($_POST['$source'],'wom') !== false) {
    $gender = 'F';
}
if(strpos($_POST['$source'],'othe') !== false) {
    $gender = 'T';
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.case.php

Comment: regular expressions may be better

Comment: I am familiar the basic CASE  but considering I have multiple "partials" that could feed, I was wondering about a more efficient syntax. Sample synyax?